# Header disappears when clicking on the back button - Ionic3

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a problem in my ionic application. When poping a page that contains an input either :

- by clicking the OK button that sends a request to the server before
  poping the current page
- or by clicking on the back button (hardware
  one or application one) The headers of the pages ((that are in the
  stack)) disappear.

This problem only appears when I emulate on the phone using `ionic cordova run android`, or when I generate the apk.
But It doesn’t show when using `ionic serve --tab` to run the application.

This is how I’m defining the header in the pages :

```
<ion-header >

  <ion-navbar >

    <button  ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>

    <ion-title  color="secondary"> Home</ion-title>

    <ion-buttons end>
      <button (click)="myFunction()" ion-button icon-only>
        <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>


  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

Here is my Ionic info :

```
 @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 7.0.1

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.0

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
    Node              : v6.11.3
    npm               : 3.10.10
    OS                : Windows 10
```

Can anyone help please ?

Comment: is this like a separate component or a header in every page?

Comment: no it's a header in every page (exect the content of  <ion-title> that changes)

Comment: Problem solved , it was due to Ionic framework version. I upgraded to 3.8.0 and things are working now.